# Excel VBA: Copy from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a workbook with two sheets in it. I need to copy data from worksheet 2 ("Detail") to worksheet 1 ("Syncrofit").  The items from ws2 I need to paste into progressive rows on sheet 1, so rows in sheet two, column B which say "Joint1-1" need to be inserted below row 1 on sheet 1.  This essentially creates a nested table.

Here's what I have so far, mostly scraped together from code and help I've found around here:

```
Sub SelectJoints()
    Sheets("Detail").Activate
    Dim Selection1 As Integer, Selection2 As Integer
    Dim SelectionRange As Range
    Dim num As Integer

    
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Set rngFind = Columns("B:B").Find(what:="*" & "Joint1-" & num, After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        Selection1 = rngFind.Row + 1
    End If

    Set rngFind = Columns("B:B").Find(what:="*Joint1-" & num + 1, After:=Range("B1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        Selection2 = rngFind.Row - 1
    End If

    If Selection1 > 0 And Selection2 > 0 Then
        Set SelectionRange = Range(Cells(Selection1, 2), Cells(Selection2, 6))
    End If
    


End Sub
```

The intent here is that this should activate the detail sheet, find strings in column B which match `SomeTextHere(Joint1-1)` and select those rows. I then need it to paste those selections over to sheet 1 (below row 1, which has a value matching the `Joint` value in one of the columns), come back to sheet 2, select the rows containing `SomeTextHere(Joint1-2)` and paste those below the next row (after those which were just inserted).  I realize that the pasting part of that is not in the code. This has been driving me nuts.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge in regards to VBA.

I'd like the finished product to look like a nested table kind of like follows:

```
               Original Items
Copied from sheet 2
Copied from sheet 2
Copied from sheet 2
               Original Item 2
Copied from sheet 2
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit bored so I whipped up something that might help you. Let me know if it works for you.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i, j, x
Dim rng As Range
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Syncrofit")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Detail")

lr = sh2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lc = sh2.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


j = 2
For y = 1 To 3 ' set upper limit of first integer in Joint string
    For x = 1 To 2 ' set upper limit of second integer in Joint string
        For i = 2 To lr
            If InStr(sh2.Cells(i, 2), "Joint" & y & "-" & x) <> 0 Then
                sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(i, 1), sh2.Cells(i, lc)).Copy
                sh1.Rows(j).Insert
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next x
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, excellent, taht should get me a good start. It adds all the values, but I need it to insert the rows, so should just be a regular paste instead of paste values, correct? Also there are Joints 2-xx, 3-xx, etc, but I should be able to either add a variable for the leading number or copy/paste the code for joint2-x, 3-x, etc. Thank you!

Comment: hmmm. So you mean rather than just pasting the values below each other, you'd like to insert the rows instead? If that's what you're looking for I modified the code to do that... and also an extra loop to handle the Joint Y-X part.

Comment: That's inserting them as rows, however it's copying the 4 columns and repeating it across the entire row.  Also, I need it to skip to the next line to insert the next 3 rows from worksheet 2 so that it basically builds a nested table between the two sheets. I edited the OP to kidn of give an example of what I mean